# RegEx for domain name extraction from Adblock rule

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract all domains from a text file and save it into another text file, but it displays all the domain names and other things, and it also returns:

```
ads.css 

abc.js 

Kashi.png
```

My input strings are:

```
token$script,domain=liveresult.ru

euroiphone.eu##.div-download-h

||ausujet.com/skins/common/ads.js

@@||cyberdean.fr/js/advertisement.js

biggestplayer.me##.adblock + *

 hearthhead.com,wowhead.com##.block-bg

 wowhead.com##.block-bgimg

  euroiphone.eu##.div-download-h

  euroiphone.eu##.div-download-v

 findretros.com##.fuck-adblock

 @@||ausujet.com/skins/common/ads.js

 @@||cyberdean.fr/js/advertisement.js

 @@||dbz-fantasy.com/ads.css

 @@||dev-dyod.fr/styles/ads.css

  forums.ru###mdl_adb

  ostroh.info###modal.modal-bg

  7days2die.info###nafikblock

 all-episodes.net###odin
```

There is lot of rule from which I have to extract domain

My  result should be:

```
liveresult.ru

cyberdean.fr

euroiphone.eu

ausujet.com

biggestplayer.me

hearthhead.com

 wowhead.com

 euroiphone.eu

  ausujet.com

  cyberdean.fr

 dbz-fantasy.com

 dev-dyod.frforums.ru

 7days2die.infoy
```

I have tried:

```
import re

   Domains = ['ru', 'fr' ,'eu', 'com']

 with open('easylist.txt', 'r') as f:

       a=f.read()

  result=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+',a)

  unique_result = list(set(result))

  for r in result:

     domain_name = r.split('.')[1]

     If  domain_name in domains:

      file_out.write(r+/n)
```

But for this I have to make a list of domain which is labours process , I want to make some pattern which automatically extract domain ignoring the things like ads.js , ads.css , advertisement.js etc , so kindly tell me where I m doing wrong .

Comment: Solution for this from your side will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print everything in a new line you should do `file_out.write(r+'\n')` to write every string on a new line, and you can remove duplicates by using `set`

```
import re

domains = ['ru', 'fr' ,'eu', 'com']
with open('easylist.txt', 'r') as f:
    a=f.read()
    result=re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+',a)
    unique_result = list(set(result))
    for r in result:
        #Extract domain name out of url
        domain_name = r.split('.')[1]
        #Check if domain name is in list of domains, only then add it
        if domain_name in domains:
            file_out.write(r)
```

Comment: and what about to remove duplication ?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: Great, please upvote and accept my answer as well to help me :)

Comment: In the above code  one more problem m facing is that it also retrieve wrong output like it return ads.js , abc.php,  kashi.png but I don't want to fetch these thing , I want that my code should skip things after / backslash , It should only include domain name , which pattern should i use ?

Comment: For it, you can check if the known domain names, e.g. `com`, `in`, `gov` etc are present in the string

Comment: Yes these are present in the string my string look like this     ||penducado.com/styles/ads.css
           @@||presse-algerie.net/js/ads.js$script 
           android.com,freeiphone.fr,hommedumatch.fr,j  
           token$script,domain=liveresult.ru                              I want to fetch only domain name not a add.css or ads.js , but when I execute my above code it fetch these thing also

Comment: Update your question with these question, it helps with better formatting and understanding too :)

Comment: Waiting for your kind response @davesh

Comment: Updated the answer! Please check!

Comment: Thank you so much @davesh  , I have a large file and in which there is lot of domain . As your answer we have to add all the extention of domain in Domain field which is manual process . I was looking for such code which extract all domain automatically so if there is any logic of regular expression regarding this kindly share . Otherwise I'll manage it somehow.

Comment: A simple google search will bring you to http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db, which is a master list of all domain names, just use this while parsing. You have to have a master list against which you can compare domain name validity, otherwise how do you know which string is a valid domain name and which is not?